# Edit help overlays on the footer in edit

Tags: bug, status-declined, edits, footer, editing-help

Not sure if it is reported, but I couldn't find any.

So, in edit page for questions/answers, when we scroll down, the help on the right will overlay on the footer.

I am not sure if it is a bug or feature, but it doesn't look friendly to me anyway.

[image]

Comment: Yep, it is duplicate! Should I close it or flag it?